# How to use filter in Microsoft Graph API to get SharePoint items?

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online, boomi

Here I am trying to filter data based on created date. At 1st I tried in Graph Explorer and it's working.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?$filter=createdDateTime ge 2017-09-04&$select=subject,lastModifiedDateTime
```

Now trying to implement same in Dell Boomi. This is resource path to pull all the items: `sites/{id}.sharepoint.com:/sites/{id}:/lists/{list_id}/items`
it's working fine.

After that I am adding filter condition:

```
sites/{id}.sharepoint.com:/sites/{id}:/lists/{list_id}/items?$filter=lastModifiedDateTime ge 2017-09-04&$select=email,displayName
```

Here is getting error. This is the error message:

```
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Bad Request</TITLE>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii"></HEAD>
<BODY><h2>Bad Request</h2>
<hr><p>HTTP Error 400. The request is badly formed.</p>
```

Can some one help on this, how to fix this issue?
Here is the Sample data.

```
> {   "@odata.context":
> "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#Collection(microsoft.graph.list)(&#39;1334af71-5b7a-4276-a8d8-c3f3f129051d&#39;)/items",
> "value": [
>     {
>       "@odata.etag": "&quot;ef6e961c-a956-400e-a77d-f044d2e0b894,8&quot;",
>       "createdDateTime": "2018-05-24T13:38:10Z",
>       "eTag": "&quot;ef6e961c-a956-400e-a77d-f044d2e0b894,8&quot;",
>       "id": "3",
>       "lastModifiedDateTime": "2018-06-18T10:24:27Z",
>       "webUrl": "https://{id}.sharepoint.com/sites/{id}/Doc%20Interfaces/757391.pdf",
>       "createdBy": {
>         "user": {
>           "email": "abc@abc.COM",
>           "id": "173abc",
>           "displayName": "abc"
>         }
>       },
>       "lastModifiedBy": {
>         "user": {
>           "email": "xyz@abc.COM",
>           "id": "234xyz",
>           "displayName": "xyz"
>         }
>       },
>       "parentReference": {
>         "id": "03fe-16595a0da875"
>       },
>       "contentType": {
>         "id": "0x01"
>       },
>       "fields@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#Collection(microsoft.graph.list)(&#39;1334f71-c3f3f129&#39;)/items(&#39;3&#39;)/fields/$entity",
>       "fields": {
>         "@odata.etag": "&quot;ef6e961-f044d2e0b894,8&quot;",
>         "FileLeafRef": "757391.pdf",
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Short Answer**

Use the auto generated SharePoint list item fields *Created* or *Modified*

```
/items?expand=fields&$filter=fields/Modified gt '2018-01-01'
```

**Important Note**

To perform filter queries on these fields, you will have to either:

- Index these columns (see how [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/add-an-index-to-a-sharepoint-column-f3f00554-b7dc-44d1-a2ed-d477eac463b0))
- Or Set the *'Prefer: HonorNonIndexedQueriesWarningMayFailRandomly'* header on your request (not recommended by Microsoft)

**Explenation**

It seems like filtering on the values that are returned by the graph endpoint (such as lastModifiedDateTime, createdDateTime, etc.) is not supported, since requests like */items&$filter=lastModifiedDateTime ge '2018-01-01'* will return a *"Invalid filter clause"* error.

Comment: This one is working for me: /items?$expand=Fields&$filter=fields/Modified lt '2018-12-28T00:00:00Z'

Comment: Not sure why it's not working for me. I tried this also tired to tweak this but not working. Same error. Not sure if dell boomi handle the this in some other way.

Comment: Thanks @JollyBrackets, this works for me but did you notice that 'equals' doesn't seem to work? I know the id of a list item but always get the "Invalid filter clause" error. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I just solved a very similar problem in submitting an OData query to Boomi. The issue was the spaces in the filter string:

Your string: $filter=lastModifiedDateTime ge '2017-09-04'
Should be: $filter=lastModifiedDateTime%20ge%20'2017-09-04'

Answer (score 0):

please try

```html
sites/{id}.sharepoint.com:/sites/{id}:/lists/{list_id}/items?$filter=lastModifiedDateTime ge '2017-09-04'&$select=email,displayName
```

`filter=lastModifiedDateTime ge '2017-09-04'` --> single quotes

NOTE : If you are selecting any lookup values you need to use `$expand` query options
 For example:

```
sites/{id}.sharepoint.com:/sites/{id}:/lists/{list_id}/items?$filter=lastModifiedDateTime ge '2017-09-04'&$select=email,displayName&$expand=displayName/Name
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. I had tried this`'2017-09-04'` before but it's not working.

Comment: Did you try with the $expand

Comment: For better understanding I have added sample data in Question. Please check. Here I am using this URL to pull the data. `sites/{id}.sharepoint.com:/sites/{id}:/lists/{list_id}/items?expand=fields`. By this I am able to get data mention above. After that I am tring to use Filter by date it's not working. This is the URL: **sites/{id}.sharepoint.com:/sites/{id}:/lists/{list_id}/items?$filter=lastModifiedDateTime ge '2017-09-04'&$expand=value/webUrl**

Comment: Also doesn't work for me. I'm not able to filter on any of the "meta" data, not even the ID (e.g. ?filter=id eq '15')